# How can one get the clipboard menu item in the contextual menu in Gmail's compose email field?

Tags: gmail, copy-paste

How can one get the clipboard menu item in the contextual menu in Gmail's compose email field?

It's not present on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S9, Android 9):

[image]

Content of the `...` menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The clipboard is a feature of the keyboard i.e. the `Input Method` in android terminology.

- Assuming you are using gboard which is google's keyboard; you should see the `clipboard` button towards the top right of the keyboard. Depending on your device, it might also be inside the 3-dot menu item that can be clicked on to expand the rest of the list.
- Clicking on this reveals more buttons. One of which is the clipboard. You could use copied items for one hour from this clipboard. In order to save items permanently, you can pin them.

Comment: Thanks, as shown in the screenshot in the question, the contextual menu that I have doesn't include "clipboard" in the options

Comment: Oh, my bad. I understand your question better now. Which keyboard application are you using?

Comment: Google's ~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks I've added content of the `...` menu in the question as a screenshot, I don't see the clipboard in it :/

Comment: In your version of the keyboard, the clipboard button itself is to the left of the 3 dot button. It seems like this is a horizontal list capable of showing 4 buttons and combines the remaining into a list that expends on pressing the 3 dots. It is possible to cycle these items around.

Comment: thanks, do you know  [how to sync the Google keyboard's clipboard with Android's clipboard?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220096/12202)